# Launch AD for alt domain batch stopped working after win10 upgrade

Tags: windows, active-directory, scripting, batch-file

I have a simple batch script that I have been using to launch the AD Users and Computers modules for domains other than the one my current session is logged in to.  I've been using this for longer than I can clearly remember, but since a recent forced upgrade of my workstation to windows 10, I can no longer get the batch to work.  Here's the guts of the batch:

```
runas /netonly /user:otherdomain.rootdomain.corp\otherdomusername "mmc dsa.msc /server=otherdomdc.otherdomain.rootdomain.com"
```

Since windows 10, This fails first because the command must be run from an elevated command prompt.  I'm researching that solution now.  The one I can't seem to solve is that even when this appears to run correctly, the new AD session is not actually launched properly under the new credentials and environment.  It launches with only the privileges of my currently logged on credentials.

I'm working around this by RDP'ing to my servers on the target domains to perform AD tasks right now, but this is a serious loss of efficiency.  Google and technet have been no help in trying to get this command working, so if anyone here knows how to get this script to work as intended on a Windows 10 workstation, I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you very much for your help.

(Cross-posting my question from stackoverflow in case someone here has run into this before.)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had mis-diagnosed the issue.  The batch was fine, but there is a bug in the current RSAT for windows 10 that made certain tabs not show up, which I had interpreted as being due to lower privileges.  I was able to resolve the issue by manually replacing certain files with their equivalents from one of my 2012 r2 servers, and now the ADUAC module launches as expected from my batch files.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue, but the RSAT tool got to be uograded at each Windows 10 upgrade, and more specific to a inplace upgrade.

See for reference; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4090941/windows-10-rsat-is-uninstalled-after-in-place-upgrade

> This is by design. RSAT is always uninstalled during in-place
>   upgrades.
>
> Resolution After the in-place upgrade of Windows 10, reinstall RSAT.